# Music stutters when other sounds are played on Xonar DX

Tags: windows-7, audio

After I installed an Asus Xonar DX soundcard, I experience that the music from Spotify/iTunes stutter when Skype plays notification alerts. This never happend with my integrated soundcard (which I've uninstalled and disabled).

I tried to install the latest driver when I installed the card, but am not really sure if I succeeded. The setup.exe failed, so I had to update the driver to latest manually (which should work fine).

Any idea how to fix this? Ask for more info if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite common issue when the first time installation failed. 
Make sure that you have deleted all the driver files before you reinstall the latest driver.
Should be OK!